# replace last occurrence in line

Tags: vim

`:%s/one/two/` will replace the *first* occurrence of `one` with `two`. Is there an easy way to replace the *last* occurrence, instead?

I can't assume it's next to the end-of-line, and there's nothing unique around the last occurrence to 'grab' to use, similar to this:

```
one two three one two three one two one two one two ...
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The easiest way would be to allow arbitrary text in front of the match, and specify the matched region using [`\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs):

```
:%s/.*\zsone/two/
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution. I have been banging my head trying to use negative-lookahead in vim for the last two hours but this one worked straight away! thanks!!

Comment: oh gosh that's magic here i want to substitute the last space with a comma %s/.*\zs /,/

Answer (score 15):

Because .* is greedy, this should work:

```
:%s/\(.*\)one/\1two/
```

Comment: nice and neat :)

Comment: sometimes greed can be exploited.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace a word in one line, you could also say:

```
$?one<CR>cetwo<ESC>
```

Which will go to the end of the line (`$`) and find backwards the word `one` (`?one<CR>`). Then it will *change* (`c`) everything up to the *end* (`e`) of the word with the string `two`. Of course you can vary `e` with `E`, `f`, `F` and so on. You could even say `c17l` to change the next 17 characters.